# .htaccess RewriteCond not working / being ignored

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, cpanel

I'm trying to set the .htaccess file in my cpanel shared hosting so that all URLs which don't exist get redirected as 301 redirects to the homepage (doing this for a specific reason).

This code works for the redirect, but the RewriteCond statements are ignored so every single URL is redirected to the homepage, even existing ones (not good).

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

#END wordpress
```

I've tried it without the %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} too with no luck and a few other things.

Does anyone know why the RewriteCond isn't working?

Comment: "I've tried it without the %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}" - You should certainly remove the `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` part. `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is already an absolute filesystem path, so prefixing the document root is not going to work (it will always fail, so your _condition_ will be true). Also, clear your browser cache... these _erroneous_ 301s will be cached by your browser.

Comment: Just to confirm... these are physical files on the filesystem? ie. outside of WordPress?

Comment: Okay thanks, I was clearing the cache each time yeah. no luck unfortunately. 

I thought the FILENAME pointed to the file (webpage) on the host server that they were searching for? I'm a beginner at all this.

So that would be like "If the url searched doesn't exist as a file (!-f) then redirect as a 301 to root url"

Comment: The `REQUEST_FILENAME` holds the absolute physical filename that the URL maps to (if any). However, the code clearly references `WordPress`? WP does not serve its pages using physical files... the content is stored in a database and the URL routed through a _front controller_. Therefore, if the pages you are trying to detect the existence of are part of WordPress then what you are trying to do will never work. "If the url searched doesn't exist as a file (!-f) then redirect as a 301 to root url" - yes.